# Why doesn't Linux have binary APIs?

Tags: linux

If I want to automate anything, I always have to end up parsing text (which has to be produced from binary anyway). An example is the `/proc` filesystem.

Is there a reason to not have binary equivalents that can be readed without parsing? Text is handy to explore on the terminal, but awful to create utilities that rely on that information.

Comment: Linux has plenty of binary format `ioctl`s on device nodes. It may or may not have a suitable one for the information you want.

Comment: `/proc` is reasonable documented [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/proc.html) among other places. Since the info is presented as text files, processing using utilities such as `awk`, `perl`, or `python` should be fairly easy and portable. Having to use a compiled language to decipher binary structures would make life much more difficult.

Comment: @doneal24 I'm not saying it has to be only binary.

Comment: Providing both text and binary interfaces to `/proc` would be redundant and I would always wonder which one was authoritative. A well-documented and consistent text interface can be very easy to work with in a script. This is exactly what `perl` was created for 30 years ago. You could actually rewrite `ps` in `perl` using the `ProcessTable.pm` module to read `/proc` fairly easily. Text input and scripted utilities do go together well.

Comment: The text one would be based on the binary one, its just an additional layer. Having the kernel or some libraries formatting data for other apps to parse it is the redundant thing.

Comment: Oh great, so you want to double the code size for what benefit exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Linux tends to evolve quickly, and frequently changes involve updating APIs like /proc.

It is very easy to modify the text API without breaking anything (for instance, add a column, make the line longer).  It is possible to make a ABI that can evolve without breaking things, but it is is much much harder, and you'd probably end up needing to parse the binary data structures to make that work anyway.

And, as pointed out in comments, the text interfaces in /proc make it very easy to use scripting languages to process it, and most of those make parsing what is in /proc trivial.

If you are having problems parsing what is in /proc, it might be best to look for a library for the language you are using that already parses /proc for you.

I believe there are a few things in /proc that are binary, but it is mostly text.  Interfaces like ioctl() are almost entirely binary.